# Detect where click happened?

Tags: python, add-on

I am writing a free add-on for Blender with a camera list showing all cameras in the scene. Clicking a camera from the list allows you to set a custom resolution for that camera.

Ideally, I want the user to be able to click anywhere to pick the camera they want to customise-not just the camera list. However, I quickly end up with a recursive loop that hangs Blender if I cannot differentiate between clicks in the camera list and clicks anywhere else.

So, is there a way to know where the user clicked, if they clicked the add-on camera list or eg. the outliner, or scene?

Comment: Hello can you post some code you tried and elaborate more on expectations.